# Java -need two threads to share the same class for simple chat server

Tags: java, tcp

I'm trying to make a simple chat server in Java.  Now I have a thread that accepts the tcp-ip connections, ads users, removes users and add comments.

I would like to erase any users who where on for x amount of time and had no contact with the chat server.  I was going to have a separate thread, that would be in a different class do this.

The problem is that the thread that accepts the connections contains a class called cUser to handle the users, and the class for doing the time out would not see this class.

In c i could just have a global.  I was thinking about making the cUser class members all static, seems a little messy.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Ted

Comment: you need to use `wait` and `notify`

Comment: are you talking about a cUser class or class instance? if it's an inner class then making it public will make it visible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If accessing the class is your main concern, then moving it into a separate file and delcaring the class public is one option.

Or you can have call back methods on the main class to be able to communicate with your inner class

```
Also you can use this.getClass().getDeclaredClasses() to access the inner class
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me some insight. The issue is that I will have 2 classes.  One class will add and remove users.  The other class acts as a clean up and will remove any users with a time out.  I need both classes to be able to use the same class that handles the users.

Comment: If you can post some code examples that will help to solve more. +1 for your question, cheers!